# JavaScript object and css classes giving issue

Tags: javascript, angular

my issue is related to Angular material but JavaScript logic is causing me issue. I have an object

```
 [  {
   "type": "holiday",
   "date": "2019-07-04",
   "releaseWindow":       {
      "start": null,
      "end": null
   },
   "description": "HMHS Holiday",
   "linkable": false
}]
```

if type of date is holiday then apply red color to calendar.
I used switch statement for that

```
// dateClass is used to apply color to calendar. If dates of calendar is matching with dates from sample data then color will be applicable
dateClass() {
  return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
    for (const items of this.datesArray) {
      switch (items.type) {

        case 'holiday':
          if (moment(items.date).year() === date.getFullYear() && moment(items.date).month() === date.getMonth() && moment(items.date).date() === date.getDate()) {
            this.holiday = true; /// apply red color
          } else {
            this.holiday = false; /// no color
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
    return [this.holiday ? 'holiday' : ''];
  }; // if this.holiday is true then apply red color to background

}
```

Below is my stackblitz link. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-c-p-5htnub?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

if you take single single object from the sample data, then you will see colors are applicable appropriately. But when you take bunch of data then its not applicable.

For example for date  "2019-07-04", in the calendar background should be red but its not. If you delete everything from the sample data and take only first object (date:"2019-07-04")then css class is applicable.

Comment: I think you aren't using "this" correctly. The way you are using this now (this.holiday), it's a global - so you can only set it to true for a maximum of one date. You need to rewrite it so you are setting the properties on the items in your array instead of "this".

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean. I am sorry got confused with "this" thing

Comment: Okay instead of this.holiday what can I use? Should I try it with let?

Comment: @Daniel you're right. how can I fix the issue. one color is applicable to only single not multiple dates. Thanks! It didn't come into my mind

Comment: @Daniel can you give me some example when you said := " You need to rewrite it so you are setting the properties on the items in your array instead of "this"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have way over-complicated the method you have. 
Here is a simplified example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-c-p-5fbu1h?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

```
  dateClass() {
    // This actually gets called for **EACH** date that's being rendered.
    // Keep this in mind.
    return (calendarDate: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
      const key = moment(calendarDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      let date = null;
      if(this.datesArray) {
        const result = this.datesArray.filter((d: any) => d.date === key);
        if(result.length > 0) {
          date = result[0];
        }
      }

      let cssClasses = '';
      if(date) {
          cssClasses = date.type;
          if(date.linkable === true) {
              cssClasses += ' set_your_linkable_class';
          }
      }

      return cssClasses;
    };
  }
```

If I were you, I'd also restructure the data or refactor the backend to return the data in a `map` format so that you can directly do `this.datesArray['2019-07-12']` and get the object directly instead of having to loop through all dates to filter it out.

Comment: hey, there are few more colors which are not applicable. For example 2019-07-07, 2019-07-14, 2019-07-21 , these are not showing any background color

Comment: That's because there is no `.outageRelease` class in the css. If you go into the `DOM` you'll see that the `td` has the class from `date.type`. Just add the class and color.

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy coding! :)

Comment: How can I apply one more css class to the dates if linkable  from the data is true?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer - `set_your_linkable_class` :)

Comment: I gave css for linkable :- .linkable {text-decoration: underline !important;} but its not applicable and I see that class in DOM. If linkable is true then underline the date

Comment: did you change the class name from `cssClasses += ' set_your_linkable_class';` to `cssClasses += ' linkable';` ?

Comment: yes, during debugging in DOM I can see linkable is applicable. But its not showing underline to date

Comment: css is probably wrong - `.linkable .mat-calendar-body-cell-content { color: white;
 background: blue; text-decoration: underline; }`